# Pydantic: Assign parent model field to a submodel field while unpacking raw data

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, pydantic

In Pydantic V2.3.0, I'm trying to assign a field in a model automatically through its "parent" object. In our use case, it's a foreign-key relationship that we'd like to auto-assign. I understand that I can loop through and assign it in the `__init__` method, but I was simply wondering if there's existing functionality that would make this easier and improve the model.

As an example, I've provided some data with a Product model, a Variant model, and sample raw data. When unpacking the raw data, it automatically creates the Variant objects inside the single Product object but without the product_id field. Is it possible to auto-assign the product_id field during the unpacking stage, and not in an `__init__` method?

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Variant(BaseModel):
    id: int
    product_id: Optional[int] # Automatically assign from Product?
    name: str
    price: float
    tax: float = 10.5

class Product(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    variants: list[Variant]

# Sample data for unpacking
p1 = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test Product",
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Variant 1",
            "price": 10.0,
            "tax": 10.5
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Test Variant 2",
            "price": 20.0,
            "tax": 10.5
        }
    ]
}

# Unpack all data, automatically assign product_id to variant
prod = Product(**p1)
```

Comment: try to use [conlist](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.conlist) instead of list

Comment: @Yechielbabani I just tried several implementations, but it seems like the conlist type can validate the type of objects inside of a list but not auto-assign the product_id field for a Variant object (as per my example). Or am I missing something?